# Sublime Text 3 Plugin changing run to on_pre_save

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext3

I have been working on a Sublime Text 3 plugin that fixes some coding standards I have at work(That I have a bad habit of missing) I currently have this working with a command run in the console. [Most of the code was originally from this thread.](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/find-and-replace-py/8761)

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ReplaceCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        #for each selected region
        region = sublime.Region(0, self.view.size())
        #if there is slected text
        if not region.empty():
            #get the selected region
            s = self.view.substr(region)

            #perform the replacements
            s = s.replace('){', ') {')
            s = s.replace('}else', '} else')
            s = s.replace('else{', 'else {')

            #send the updated string back to the selection
            self.view.replace(edit, region, s)
```

Then you just need to run:

```
view.run_command('replace')
```

And it will apply the coding standards(there are more I plan to implement but for now i'll stick with these) I would like this to run on save.

I tried just changing run(self, edit) to on_pre_save(self, edit) but it does not work. I don't get any syntax errors but It just doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me how to make this run on save instead of having to run the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On ST3 the only way to get an `Edit` object is by running a `TextCommand`. (It's in the [docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.Edit), but they're not terribly clear). But, fortunately, you can run the command pretty much the same way you have been doing.

Events handlers, like `on_pre_save`, can only be defined on an [`EventListener`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener). The `on_pre_save()` event is passed a view object so you just need to add something like this, which kicks-off the command you've already written.

```
class ReplaceEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_pre_save(self, view):
        view.run_command('replace')
```

Comment: I literally just figured this out before I saw this lol. I had already written a TabsToSpaces/SpacesToTabs plugin that ran a command. Then I put 2 and 2 together.

Answer (score 0):

The Solutions I came to was to create an on_pre_save() function that runs the command I listed earlier:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
class ReplaceCodeStandardsCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        #for each selected region
        region = sublime.Region(0, self.view.size())
        #if there is slected text
        if not region.empty():
            #get the selected region
            s = self.view.substr(region)

            #perform the replacements
            s = s.replace('){', ') {')
            s = s.replace('}else', '} else')
            s = s.replace('else{', 'else {')

            #send the updated string back to the selection
            self.view.replace(edit, region, s)

class ReplaceCodeStandardsOnSave(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    # Run ST's 'unexpand_tabs' command when saving a file
    def on_pre_save(self, view):
        if view.settings().get('update_code_standard_on_save') == 1:
            view.window().run_command('replace_code_standards')
```

Hopefully this code helps someone!